# Select rows of matrix in same range

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix like this:

```
a=[ 20 30 45 55;
    25 25 50 60;
   100 29 36 52;
    28 33 48 62];
```

I want to have another matrix such that rows of this new matrix are in the range of ±10 of the first row of the `a` matrix.
For example in this case we have matrix `b`:

```
b=[20 30 45 55;
   25 25 50 60;
   28 33 48 62]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract all rows from the first row using [**`bsxfun`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) (or [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/#9291e878-13cd-4805-8040-af9ddde8b24b) if you have MATLAB 2016b or later) and take the [**`abs`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html)olute value. Then use [**`any`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) with [**`~`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html) to find those rows of `a` which do not contain any value outside the ±10 range of the first row. Then finally use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to select those rows.

**Code:**

```
b = abs(bsxfun(@minus, a,a(1,:)));
b = a(~any(b>10,2),:);
```

**Output for given `a`:**

```
b = 
    20    30    45    55
    25    25    50    60
    28    33    48    62
```

Comment: two more questions... if I want to know the index of selected rows of matrix a what can I write this ... and if I want to classify rows of matrix a in which for example m entries of rows (m<n columns of matrix a) are in same range how can I write this